# Does it matter which side I place the bulb in a circuit?

Tags: circuit-design

For example, will it matter if the bulb is in this position:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ2Ki9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

or this position?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV3MXu.png)</sup>

Also, if it wouldn't work in either position, why? I mean, in the second, charged electrons are still being passed through the bulb, right?

Comment: There is no difference between both circuits, one side of the bulb is in both cases connected to plus of the battery and the switch is between minus of the battery and the other side of the bulb.
The other possible circuit with the switch between plus and the bulb would work also. If the switch is closed, electrons will flow through the bulb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as a simple circuit like this is concerned, there is no difference. The three components that make up the circuit (battery, bulb and switch) are all connected in series.

This is of course a simple ideal case (which is perfectly OK in a pure circuit theory point of view), presumably in an hobby context.

If we consider what this circuit is connected to *outside its ideal world*, it depends on the context. For example, if the battery were not a battery but a earth-grounded power supply and the bulb had a metallic enclosure also connected to earth-ground (safety ground). These external connection would matter in some cases.

Anyway, as long as the circuit exactly represents what it shows (a real-world 9V battery, a light bulb and a switch), then what I said still stands.

**Note:** my emphasis about when these circuits might not be equivalent is prompted by my impression that you are a newbie. Sometimes newbies post a circuit that don't represent *exactly* what's in it. Or sometimes also they think that the answer is easily applicable to "slightly" different situations, and this brings up safety concerns. For example: what I said could be applicable also if the battery were a household power outlet, ***but only in theory*** (the theory where the power outlet is seen as a simple AC voltage generator). In practice, in such cases there are safety issues to be considered which call for a deep understanding of what's the real environment "where the circuit lives".

Another thing to notice is that the position of the switch may matter if you are engineering a product, then the physical size of the components and the routing of the actual wires used for the connections may dictate whether one of the circuit is better than the other, although electrically they will behave the same.

Comment: When would there be a difference? And why? Would it be different in parallel?

Comment: Also, nice guess that I'm a noob lol

Comment: @SuperNinja741DoesGaming If you connect the switch in parallel with the bulb. The bulb will always be on and the switch won't have any effect

Comment: @Hayman No. If the switch were in parallel, the bulb would be on with the switch open, and would be off with the switch closed, but in this latter case the switch would also short-circuit the battery (not a good thing [tm]).

Answer (score 0):

The schematics are exactly the same: the "+" of the battery is connected to a contact on the switch. The other contact is connected to a terminal of the bulb, and the other terminal of the bulb is connected to the "-" of the battery.

Since the bulb and the switch are symmetrical (you can turn them around and they will physically act the same way), the schematics are electrically identical.

This said, just from a *human-readable* standpoint, the second schematic
appears better to me: when you draw a schematic, it's more natural to have the signal travel from left to right - so I would prefer that the battery be on the left, being a power source. Actually, I would draw it such that the bulb is on the right, so it's clear that this is where the "signal" or "information" terminates. Of course, this is strictly in the intuitive sense, and has little to do with the actual flow of electricity.

Comment: "actual flow of electricity" doesn't mean anything, from a technical standpoint. Charges may flow. Current flows. "Electricity" is the common term for a general class of phenomena. Electricity doesn't flow anywhere.